# Is it possible to do this object declaration inline

Tags: coffeescript

I have this bit of coffeescript for declaring a form element

```
validation = {}

if isRequired 
  validation.required = 
    params: true 
    message: "Please enter a year between #{minYear} & #{maxYear}."

@Year = new inputFormItem
  validation: validation
```

Is it possible to do an inline declaration of this?

Something like this but what I've written doesn't compile

```
@Year = new inputFormItem
  validation: 
    if isRequired then required: { params: true, message: "Please enter a year between #{minYear} & #{maxYear}." }
```

I don't know if it's possible to put inline conditionals in object declarations

If required is true then I need the object otherwise I don't want a required object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Year = new inputFormItem
  validation: 
    required: if isRequired then { params: true, message: "Please enter a year between #{minYear} & #{maxYear}." } else null
```

This will default to `null` (you could do `undefined` if you want). If you want it to default to `false`, then you can do this:

```
@Year = new inputFormItem
  validation: 
    required: isRequired and { params: true, message: "Please enter a year between #{minYear} & #{maxYear}." }
```

Comment: undefined works - null didn't - but that could be something to do with the library I'm using for validation - thank you :D

Comment: Yep, it's probably checking `typeof validation.required !== "undefined"` instead of truthiness checking.